# How to change table view cell text label color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've searched here a lot, and I found a lot of people telling to put the code inside `if (cell == nil)`, I did it, but it didn't work.

My code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [listaMaterias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:17/255 green:112/255 blue:1/255 alpha:1];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're creating your UIColor, you're using integer division. 17/255 = 0. You want to use floating-point division: [UIColor colorWithRed:17.0f/255.0f green:112.0f/255.0f blue:1.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f].

Incidentally, that (cell == nil) check isn't necessary, because it's legal to call methods on nil, they just won't do anything (and will return nil if they return an object). So "(nil).textLabel" evaluates to nil, and "(nil).textColor =" (which becomes "[nil setTextColor:]) just returns immediately.

Answer (score 0):

[`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier%3aforIndexPath%3a) always returns a valid cell, thus cell is never `nil` and that code is never executed. The advice you were following before is for when `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` is used, and could return `nil`, and thus cell creation was required in the `cell == nil` block.

You can just call it directly, as long as you also change your color creation code to what @Sean Cier pointed out.